# Can Angular 2 pass a complex object along the router?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Is it possible to send a complex object through a router?
Here is what I'm doing and trying to do:

From the search page, a use can click a button on one of the results which calls the method that causes this line to fire. `this.router.navigate(['profile-detail', selection]);`

The `selection` object looks like this just before the navigate.

```
{
  profile: {
    id: number,
    fname: string,
    lname: string
  },
  contact: {
    type: string,
    address: string
  },
  books: [{
    title: string,
    author: string
  }]
}
```

However, when we get to the profile-detail page, the `this.route.snapshot.params` has this as the actual data:

```
{
  profile: "[object Object]",
  contact: "[object Object]",
  books: "[object Object]"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the router needs to serialize the data to the browsers URL bar, and the URL bar only supports a string.

You can use a shared service to pass objects between components that are not parent/child or siblings or dynamically added like the router does.

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

A resolver might also work depending on your concrete requirements https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard

Comment: @TimConsolazio `EventEmitter` is supposed to be only used with `@Output()` in components. In services use observables instead. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35568924/217408, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html

Comment: Thanks, I had seen a similar answer in other similar questions. But your explanation on serialization was missing from those other answers.

Comment: Again, Angular 1.x recommended many things the field in general abandoned. And for the record, I found it extremely constructive.

Comment: Subject is `RxJS`

Answer (score 1):

another can be using JSON.stringify and save your object in local storage or session storage and have it widely available in entire app